# Need "number" field validation rule to accept 08445611044 for ireland companies please help. Currently not accepting this number

Tags: validation-rule, validation, fields, number

The current validation rule, is not accept the number **08445611044**:

```
If( ISPICKVAL( Region__c,"NI"),NOT(REGEX(Phone, "0[1-9]{1}[0-9]{8,9}")) ,

If( ISPICKVAL( Region__c,"SCT"),NOT(REGEX(Phone, "0[1-9]{1}[0-9]{8,9}")),

If( ISPICKVAL( Region__c,"NE"),NOT(REGEX(Phone, "0[1-9]{1}[0-9]{8,9}")),

If( ISPICKVAL( Region__c,"Rest of UK"),NOT(REGEX(Phone, "0[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}")),

If(AND(BillingCountry = "Ireland",ISPICKVAL( Region__c,"ROI")),NOT(REGEX(Phone, "00[1-9]{3}[0-9]{7,9}")),

If(AND(BillingCountry = "",ISPICKVAL( Region__c,"ROI")),NOT(REGEX(Phone, "0[1-9]{1}[0-9]{8,9}")),

If(BillingCountry = "US",NOT(REGEX(Phone, "00[1]{1}[0-9]{10}")),

NOT(REGEX(Phone, "[0-9]{11,14}")))))))))
```

Comment: As per the validation rule, for Ireland phone number start with 00 . It is allowing 008445611044

Answer (score 1):

As per your current validation rule, for Ireland the phone number should start with 00.

If you want to allow the phone number 08445611044 for ireland then you need to modify your validation rule like below.

```
If( ISPICKVAL( Region__c,"NI"),NOT(REGEX(Phone, "0[1-9]{1}[0-9]{8,9}")) ,

If( ISPICKVAL( Region__c,"SCT"),NOT(REGEX(Phone, "0[1-9]{1}[0-9]{8,9}")),

If( ISPICKVAL( Region__c,"NE"),NOT(REGEX(Phone, "0[1-9]{1}[0-9]{8,9}")),

If( ISPICKVAL( Region__c,"Rest of UK"),NOT(REGEX(Phone, "0[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}")),

If(AND(BillingCountry = "Ireland",ISPICKVAL( Region__c,"ROI")),NOT(REGEX(Phone, "0[1-9]{3}[0-9]{7,9}")),

If(AND(BillingCountry = "",ISPICKVAL( Region__c,"ROI")),NOT(REGEX(Phone, "0[1-9]{1}[0-9]{8,9}")),

If(BillingCountry = "US",NOT(REGEX(Phone, "00[1]{1}[0-9]{10}")),

NOT(REGEX(Phone, "[0-9]{11,14}")))))))))
```

Replaced NOT(REGEX(Phone, `"00`[1-9]{3}[0-9]{7,9}")) to NOT(REGEX(Phone, `"0`[1-9]{3}[0-9]{7,9}"))